# Why does 4 > +4 evaluate to false?

Tags: python

Why does the expression `4 >+4` return `False`?

#### Example

```
    4 > +4
    #False
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Python does not have a unary numeric incrementation operator. `+4` simply means 'apply the `+` operator to `4`'. The unary `+` operator returns it's numeric value unchanged:

```
>>> +4
4
```

It exists to mirror the unary `-` operator, which returns the value negated:

```
>>> -4
-4
```

It does **not** mean 'add 1 to 4'.

If instead you meant to test for greater than *or equality*, then do so:

```
>>> 4 >= 4
True
```

`>` only means 'greater than' and clearly, 4 is not greater than 4.

Comment: I'm wondering if the OP is thinking of `>=` here... (that and the `+` you've pointed out are the only reasons I can think of the possible confusion with the question!)

Comment: Why would +4 involve an infix operator?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: Confusion with `++4`. Yes, it's a guess, but one that makes the most sense as to what the OP expected to happen.

Comment: OK, but still, where do infix operators come into it. ++x is not infix.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: Ah, no, that's me mixing up terminology; vocabulary corrected.

Comment: That's better. Interesting voting here.

Comment: And sorry to be picky, but no language that I know of allows in place incrementing of literals.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: Nope, none do. But if `+` returned the literal number +1 then the expression would make sense. :-)

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: There: "unary numeric incrementation operator". Would that suffice?

Comment: I'm just picking on you 'cos you are leading the race this year, and you got four upvotes here with a technical inaccuracy. I'm done tweaking you though. I'm calling off the hounds!!  :-)

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: Hey, I appreciate the feedback, actually! Sorry, didn't mean to sound snippy there. That's why I keep coming back, because SO keeps challenging me. Thanks for calling me out on my terminology!

Comment: You weren't snippy. You never are. I'm just playing' with ya. Sunday night. Bit of fun. Keep up the excellent work!!

Answer (score 1):

```
print +4 == 4
```

**Output**

```
True
```

+4 and 4 are the same. Thats why `4 > +4` returns `False`

Answer (score 0):

No number is larger than itself, so 4 is not greater than 4.

---

Note that the unary plus has nothing to do with it:

```
In [1]: 4 > +4
Out[1]: False

In [2]: 4 > 4
Out[2]: False
```